# Input Extraction in text files

Tags: java

I am trying split the text with the help of **space delimited** what I am expecting output is

Example:

The input is:

```
Allon, Wlaker D
Jessy, Ruswell A
Alex III, Paul A
Jersy, Mallen
Annie, Mathew K (Kathy)
```

The output is:

```
Wlaker D Allon
Ruswell A Jessy
Paul A Alex III
```

"Annie, Mathew K (Kathy)" this is I should remove the **(Kathy)** and the output has been

```
Mathew K Annie
```

Here the my program for your reference:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class InputExtract {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputpath="G:/Physician_East/PhyscianEast/Input/Input.txt";
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputpath));
        String data="";
        while((data=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] patinfo=data.split("\t");
            String patname=patinfo[0];
            String Addr1=patinfo[2];
            String CityStateZip=patinfo[6];
            String Appdate=patinfo[8];
            String correctname[]=patname.split(" ");
            int num=correctname.length;
            if(num==3){
                String patientname=correctname[1]+" "+correctname[2]+" " +correctname[0].replaceAll(",", "");
                System.out.println(patientname+"\t\t"+Addr1+"\t\t"+CityStateZip+"\t\t"+Appdate);
            }
            else if(num==4 ){
                String patientname=correctname[2]+" "+correctname[3]+" "+correctname[0]+" "+correctname[1].replaceAll(",", "");
                System.out.println(patientname+"\t\t"+Addr1+"\t\t"+CityStateZip+"\t\t"+Appdate);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? How to remove `(Kathy)`?

Comment: I want to show the following format "First name middle name last name" but this name "Annie, Mathew K (Kathy)" remove the "Kathy" and print Mathew K Annie